# Abstract Class and Tasks in Javafx

Tags: multithreading, javafx, concurrency

I am working on a simple file reader tool in java and I am facing an issue with task declare on an abstract class. I have a button "run" in UI which fire a method "start" to read and write informations from a file. The reason why I am using an AbstractClass is because I have different Impl. as I have different treatment on the same file. ex bellow:

Abstract Class

```
public abstract class AbstractService {

    ArrayList<Info> info = new ArrayList<Info>();

    public AbstractService() {
        super();
    }

    protected void start() {
        run();
        finish();
    }

    protected void run() {
        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {

                final List<File> files = in.getFiles();
                for(File file : files) {
                    String filename = file.getName();
                    readLines(file);
                }
                finishWorkForSelect(filename);

                return null;
            }
        };
        new Thread(task).start();
    }

    protected void readLines(File file) {
        //is Override in Impl class of a specific worker
    }

    protected void addData() {
        //is Override in Impl class of a specific worker
    }

    protected void finishWorkForSelect(String filename) {
        finishWorkForProcess(filename); //method Override in Impl class
    }

    protected void finish() {
        finishWork();
        writeData();
    }

    protected void writeData() {
        //writing data from info arraylist
    }
```

Example of a worker implementation class:

```
public class WorkerOneServiceImpl extends AbstractService implements Service {

    /** 
     * @see Service#process()
     */
    @Override
    public void process() { 
        super.start();
    }

    /**
     * @see AbstractService#readLines(file)
     */
    @Override
    protected void readLines(File file) {
        //calling addData() 
    }

    @Override
    protected void addData() {
        //code 
    }

    @Override
    protected void finishWorkForProcess(filename) {
        // Will create only on file for all processes 
    }

    @Override
    protected void finishWork() {
        //calling for another method for creating excel file on one process 
    }
```

When I run the tool, the main thread will passing through all these methods and nothing will be written in the .xlsx file. I tried to add synchronized keyword to the Override readLines() method but with no success. Same test by adding changing the readLines() method as:

```
@Override
    protected void readLines(File file) {
        synchronized (AbstractService.class) {
            //code
        }
    }
```

but with no success again. I know abstractclass could not be instanciate so no Object to lock. Furthermore, if I move the code within writeData() into addData() method, it works.

Is there a possibility to synchronized these methods through this abstract class or am I missed something?

Comment: You execute `finish()` immediately, without waiting for the `Task` to complete. Is there a reason you don't put the call to `finish()` as the last line of the `Task`'s `call()` method?

Comment: Yes because in the task and just after readLines(), I have another method who's called finishWorkerForSelect() - this method will do something similar to finish() but without using the ArrayList info declare as an attribute in the AbstractClass. Some readed information need to be added to "info" and some other information need to written by the finishWorkerForSelect() separately.

Comment: I don't really understand that. I guess the question is, when do you want `finish()` to execute? (And, I suppose, is there a particular thread you need it to be executed on?)

Comment: I edited the code above as you could have a better understanding of my issue :) - For sure, I want to execute the finish() method after the task is done.

Comment: I still don't understand why you don't just call `finish()` after `finishWorkForSelect(...)`?

Comment: You right! I don't know why but I was sure that's an issue cause by thread but in fact I just have to move the 'finish()' method into 'setOnSucceed()' and it worked fine. Thanks for the tips. Sometimes solution is before our eyes but nothing comes up to our brain :)